# Importing external python file in DataprocSubmitJobOperator on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I want to send a zipfile which has common python scripts to DataprocSubmitJobOperator. Here are my job parameters.

```
COMMON = "gs://my-bucket/common/common.zip"
INGEST_JOB_URI = f"pyspark-file.py"

job = {
        "reference": {"project_id": project_id},
        "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
        "pyspark_job": {
            "main_python_file_uri": INGEST_JOB_URI,
            "jar_file_uris":[DELTA_CORE_JAR_FILE_URI,GRAPHFRAME_JAR_FILE_URI, BQ_JAR_FILE_URI],
            "properties": {
                "spark.sql.extensions":"io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension",
                "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog":"org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
            "python_file_uris": COMMON
            },
        "archive_uris": [COMMON],
        "args": args
        },
    }
```

On my main python script `pyspark-file.py(INGEST_JOB_URI)`, I want to import the common.zip file as such:

```
from common.file_1 import myfunction
```

I've tried adding the path on archive_uris & properties but still got this error on Airflow:

```
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: python_file_uris
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/file.py", line 11, in <module>
    from common.file_1 import myfunction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

How do I import the common.zip file though DataprocSubmitJobOperator?